# how to browse docker image without running it?

Tags: docker, beyondcompare

Is there any why to browse a docker image using ssh or equivalent?
My motivation is to compare two docker images using beyond compare

edit: i am not interested in just listing file names, I need the content and I would like to be able compare two images, including content of the files.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, since this question specifically asks how to view image content "without running it". The linked question has answers that touch on that, but it is not the main discussion.

Comment: this is not duplicate. looks like who ever marked duplicate did not pay attention on "without running" part.

Comment: One solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141391/how-to-view-files-inside-docker-image-without-running-it

Answer (score 12):

If what you want is exploring a docker image then you can use a tool named [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive).

You cannot directly compare files content but at least you can browse layer contents and see which files have been added/removed/modified/unmodified.

To analyze a Docker image simply run:

```sh
dive <your_image>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like `docker image history <your image name here>`
This will give you the history of how the image is build and you could compare it to another image...

or `docker inspect <your image name here>`

Comment: Not what I expected to find, but `docker inspect <name>` actually was useful to debug entrypoint. Thanks!