# How to view files inside docker image without running it? (NOTE: THIS QUESTION IS HOW TO READ FILES WITHOUT RUNNING THE CONTAINER)

Tags: docker

Sometimes running the docker image fails so ssh’ing into the container is not an option. in that cases how do we see the content inside container?

There is a existing question but mistakenly marked as duplicate. [how to browse docker image without running it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243471/how-to-browse-docker-image-without-running-it)

NOTE: To stupid Moderators with stupid EGO, Please read the question PROPERLY before making judgement about closing the problem. Don't think you know better than others.

Comment: The duplicate target of the question you cited has a couple of examples that don't involve running the container (`docker export` trying to examine the `/var/lib/docker` content directly).  Mostly, though, you do need to actually run the image in some form to look around.

Comment: Also consider `docker run --rm -it imagename bash` to get a temporary container, running an interactive shell instead of the default image `CMD`.  This will let you explore things, and also try just running what the standard command should have been and see how it fails.

Comment: 1. I correctly stated that the question stated as duplicate is not a duplicate.

Comment: 2. the intention of this question IS TO EXAMINE WITHOUT RUNNING THE DOCKER CONTAINER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

you can add something like to override the entry point in the Dockerfile and run `ls` or `cat` command to see inside.

```
ENTRYPOINT ls /etc/fluentd
```

Comment: You can also `docker run --rm --entrypoint ls imagename /etc/fluentd` without modifying the Dockerfile.  This is kind of awkward, and you might update the Dockerfile to use `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`; then you could `docker run --rm imagename ls /etc/fluentd`.

Comment: How is this "not running the container"? You're setting up all the namespaces -- the filesystem namespace, the user namespace, the PID namespace -- and invoking a process inside it. That's running the container. In particular, if the container contains a compromised `ls` executable, you just invoked that executable. (Even worse, if it contains a compromised `/bin/sh` executable, you just ran _that_, because this is really running `sh -c 'ls /etc/fluentd'` in the container).

Comment: Whereas the `docker export` answer in the linked duplicate **really is** operating without running the container at all, and -- unlike the answer here -- works even if the container doesn't have `sh` or `ls` executables inside it. So that duplicate genuinely does have a legitimate answer to your question as you asked it, whereas the answer you added yourself doesn't meet your own specification.